# Correct Use of the SQL String_Split and Substring function

Tags: sql, json, split, substring, outsystems

I have the SQL code below, where the @Province input parameter is in this form: *"[""Central District","Central Region","Delaware","Drenthe","Eastern Cape","Free State","Gauteng","Hardap Region","Haryana","Karas Region","KwaZulu Natal","KwaZulu-Natal","Limpopo","Lorestan Province","Mpumalanga","North West","Northern Cape","Pennsylvania","Qarku i Tiranës","State of Rio de Janeiro","Toscana","Wes-Kaap","Western Cape""]"* However when I test my SQL I get no rows returned. Please assist.

```
WITH ProvinceList as (
    SELECT CAST (value AS nvarchar) name FROM STRING_SPLIT(SUBSTRING(@Provinces, 3, LEN(@Provinces)-3), ',')
)

SELECT {Site}.*
FROM {Site}

WHERE ({Site}.[Province] IN -- Get all Province names in list sent
        (SELECT name 
        FROM ProvinceList))
            
ORDER BY {Site}.[Name] ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the STRING_SPLIT your list will consist of names like *"Eastern Cape"* and *"Free State"* **with the quotation mark**. Most likely you do not have quotation marks in your table, so you need to remove those characters from the input.

```
SET @Provinces = REPLACE(@Provinces, '"', '')
WITH ProvinceList as (
    SELECT CAST (value AS nvarchar) name FROM STRING_SPLIT(SUBSTRING(@Provinces, 2, LEN(@Provinces)-2), ',')
)
```